# How to force quit and restart a service every hour?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, automator

### The Underlying Problem

This is rather specific to my machine but basically, because of how my Mac, dock, & keyboard are connected, my keyboard software (Corsair iCUE) will occasionally freeze/hang until I go into activity manager and force quit it.

It happens once every day or 2 and the specific cause is not known, but it has never happened within a few hours of me restarting the service.

As a result, none of my macros, media keys, custom scripts, lighting effects, etc. work while iCue is frozen.

### The Desired Workaround

Given how specific this issue is to my setup and that iCUE is in beta for Mac, I don't expect Corsair to fix it anytime soon.

Also, given that this issue never happens when I have recently restarted the service, my ideal workaround would be to simply force-restart it every hour or so. (It's a lightweight service, so restarting should be near-instant)

**My Question:** How can I force quit and then restart a service every hour?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information to help!

Comment: if it's in beta for Mac, wouldn't it be better to report it to the developer, so they could fix it by release??

Comment: It has been reported, but I also wouldn't count on Corsair to fix it.

Comment: Gotta be the cynic here....you've reported it, but you're not counting on them to fix it yet you still bought (aka gave them money for) their product?

Comment: The issue didn't appear until a few months ago when I started working from home. By then I was way past my return period, and until then it had worked fine.

Comment: To keep everyone updated.  Nick was right, the software is out of beta, but they didn't care enough to fix this bug 18 months later.  Returned my Corsair equipment.  Stay away Mac Users, and vote with your wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, `ps -ef` to identify a search string for the process you want to kill.

Then the script can find it by

```
ICPID=$(ps -ef | grep "searchstring" | awk '{print $2}') # find the PID

kill -9 $ICPID                                           # kill it

<full path to executable>                                # restart it
```

The 9 is the signal to send to the process.  From the man page:

Some of the more commonly used signals:

```
 1       HUP (hang up)
 2       INT (interrupt)
 3       QUIT (quit)
 6       ABRT (abort)
 9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
 14      ALRM (alarm clock)
 15      TERM (software termination signal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On a side note, it unclear if this equivalent to a "force quit" or a regular "quit". In this case, it is important that it is equivalent to a "force quit". (Regular quit just continues to hang) Could you tell me what this is equivalent to?

Comment: kill -9 is force quit

Comment: Rather than `ps | grep | awk` (!), `pgrep -i iCUE` would return the pid of the application (assuming it's name contained the word `"iCUE"`), and `pkill -i iCUE` cuts out the intermediary step altogether and just goes in for the kill.

Comment: Some literature on signal termination codes caution against using `SIGKILL` (9). Probing what signals the system receives reveals that _Activity Monitor_ does seem to use `SIGKILL` to force quit; _Finder_ uses `SIGTERM` (the default signal) to force quit, and an Apple Event to quit (which is probably why it doesn't do anything). It might be prudent to use the lowest grade signal that achieves what you want. If it were me, I'd experiment with `pkill -$quit -i iCUE` where `$quit` is the first from this list that succeeds: `TERM, HUP, INT, QUIT, ABRT, KILL` (or `15, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9`).

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the advice, I ended up googling around with original answer as a base and found `killall -9 iCUE || true` which essentially is the same thing as far as I can tell. `iCUE` is unique to that software on my system, so I am not terribly worried about accidentally killing some unrelated process.